# What does "be apparent in" mean?

Tags: meaning, collocation

*since it is acknowledged that one’s mastery of language is apparent in their collection of vocabulary, strengthening your vocabulary is a must to anyone and everyone.*

"be apparent in" is a collocation I have never seen before.What does it mean?

Comment: I think you need something like ***breadth, scale, extent*** of vocabulary (***collection*** doesn't work in this context).. And I personally don't like the switch from ***one's*** to ***their*** here. The use of ***apparent*** is perfectly ordinary English, but you might find it easier to understand with the contextually equivalent ***is manifest / shown / demonstrated / revealed** in / by / through one's breadth of vocabulary.*

Comment: _Apparent_ is related to _appear_.  How good you are at speaking language _appears_ from the size of your vocabulary.